# Creating table in MySQL Workbench 6.1

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL and am trying to create a simple table, but I'm getting the following error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '{ Movie_ID int, Title varchar(60), Genre
>   varchar(30), Director varchar(30), Star' at line 1

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Movies {
Movie_ID int,
Title varchar(60),
Genre varchar(30),
Director varchar(30),
Star varchar(30),
ReleaseDate year(),
Grade int,
Rating varchar(5),
};
```

I tried Googling MySQL 6.1 manual, but couldn't find what I needed.

Comment: Dont you mean mysql Workbench 6.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table declarations use parenthesis, not brackets:

```
CREATE TABLE Movies (
    Movie_ID int,
    Title varchar(60),
    Genre varchar(30),
    Director varchar(30),
    Star varchar(30),
    ReleaseDate year(),
    Grade int,
    Rating varchar(5)
);
```

Comment: Ah Okay thanks. Now it's saying my last line is incorrect. is using ');' not right?

Comment: Get rid of the last comma after `Rating varchar(5)`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for helping with my stupid mistakes.

Comment: @Brett, also I think `year()` should be changed to `year` or `year(4)`